# Using jQuery .hide() in a function with element id passed in

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK I must admit confusion.  I'm trying to build a simple hide function that will accept 3 vars passed in (type = id/class, ident = id/class name(without the # or .) and speed = slow/fast/400/etc...)  when I call the function the DOM element is not being hidden.

```
function ElementHide(type, ident, speed) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'id':
            if (typeof speed === 'undefined') {
                $('#' + ident).hide();
            } else {
                $('#' + ident).hide(speed);
            }
            break;
        case 'class':
            break;
    }
}
```

If I call the same function and place the actual object id/class it does hide, it just won't hide using the var ident.

```
function ElementHide(type, ident, speed) {
    $('#tblEast').hide();
    switch (type) {
        case 'id':
            if (typeof speed === 'undefined') {
                $('#' + ident).hide();
            } else {
                $('#' + ident).hide(speed);
            }
            break;
        case 'class':
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the function?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Either you're not calling the function with an ID, or the ID doesn't exist, or that part of the code isn't reached because the case statement doesn't match.

Comment: Also, use console.log(ident) to check if you are passing the right string onto the function

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ULVMP/

Comment: I'm guessing the function is being called with the hash in the element ID.

Comment: Aren't you just recreating the *exact* functionality of `.hide()` with a selector anyway? Is `ElementHide("class","myclass","slow")` really easier than just `$(".myclass").hide("slow")`?

Comment: @MattBurland Not sure of the reason, but I'm guessing he is trying to make an abstraction over jQuery, so that it would be easier to swap out the DOM-manipulation code in case you want to switch library, without searching through your entire code base replacing jQuery snippets.

Comment: I'm calling the function thusly:

  ElementHide('id', 'tlbEast');

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson You're half right, the abstraction was a welcome by-product.  I have lots of elements being show/hidden based on user and other criteria.  I was trying this as a way to loop through and pass all elements at once to hide.  If there is a better way anyone can think of I'm definitely open to other options. :)